# How to appending url path in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using `$(this).attr("href");` in jQuery Ajax `url` field gives the URL path but when i use a prefix in front of it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET'
    url: 'api/'+ $(this).attr("href");
})
```

it doesn't work.

Whats going wrong? Is this wrong method or is there a better way?

Comment: semicolon out of place, missing comma =

Comment: You are missing a `,` after "GET" and delete the `;` after `attr("href")`

Comment: `$(this)` will only work if you have an element already selected.. use `$("#myelem").attr("href")` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` -> will return a wrong result in the object.

Get the value in another place and add the ready result;

```
var getURL = 'api/'+ $(this).attr("href"); // In the level,where your $(this) is the actual this

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getURL
});
```

Comment: How would you know, the `$.ajax` function doesn't really have any other scope than what surrounds it?

Comment: @adeneo I give a global solution. Of course it can has many scopes

Comment: Oh, okay, as long as it's a global solution, it's okay, +1 !

Comment: After reading this answer, have a look at [this useful post](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) which is detailing very well how variable scoping works in JavaScript (and therefore in jQuery as well).

Comment: Sure doesn't seem like it ?

Comment: Ahahah, How did you feel it, by smelling?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan, I am sorry, I was writing the comment for OP, but looked like was written for you.